# Write my own syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, token

i'm trying to write my own code syntax highlighter, but my only difficulty is deciding how to begin to deal with the code. For example, to parse each token i must do it only with regex? Or maybe i must split code for each space? Or for each line? I know that i must be able to keep a separation between words to prevent double matching. For example, if i want to search all keywords like "*this, var, in, return etc.*" is obvious that in *this.index* match **index** also.

So, based on your experience, what are your opinions?

Comment: There's already awesome solutions for it. Why do you want to make your own?

Comment: It could be for personal exploration

Comment: lan: Because i need to build new one for one of my projects.
Snakes and Coffee: I know but i ask there for last resource, this means that I'm in a blind spot

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee That's true for anything. The OP doesn't mention what they want to use this for; that's why I asked

Comment: Securely not to highlight snippets in my blog :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice question. I've made similar research when I developed my own programming language (only for proof-of-concept). I researched the implementation of JSLint and JSMin by Douglas Crockford. I saw that he tokenize the code by reading the source symbol by symbol. You can see this approach [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSMin/blob/master/jsmin.c) and [here](https://github.com/mgechev/ELang/blob/master/src/org/mgechev/edulang/lexer/Lexer.java) for example. Actually you need just the tokenization before highlighting the code so I think that this approach will fit best. Following this you will create advanced parser which will be less error premised. Probably you'll also have greater code reuse when creating highlighters for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather advice you to look at the existing solutions. As for me - i'm very impressed of this highlighter - 
http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

It uses plugins to parse different languages - you might have good experience looking in it.

Comment: Mine is a logical programming question.. it's easy to create some working code based on another, but nobody does anything new. 
Thank you for your response, I had already thought of this, but I want a logical and unconditional solution

Comment: Yours is not very practical question (smart people (read as boooring though) using existing solutions). I just think that little theiry is never redundant. But sometimes practical implementation makes theory clearer. That's the point.

Comment: Right, "smart people"... the smart people have created these problems and have found their own solutions, thinks the first creator of syntax highlighting.
I'm still not a "smart person" but I want to become it..